# drush not able to download and enable modules whenever executing drush en <module_name> on Windows OS

Tags: drush

I keep getting this pop-up screen that tries to locate an app to open .launcher files whenever I try to execute `drush en <Module_Name>` commands to download and enable a module on Drupal 8. On mac nothing like this happens, I'm not sure what needs to be done in order for the commands to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First, use composer require for module installation.

Second, I don't use windows long time, but as I remember, there is a PATH variables that need to be configured so drush can work properly.

Take a look at this: https://modulesunraveled.com/drush/installing-drush-windows